Determine time that minimum value occurred using Google Sheets
I have a set of sampled data consisting of date/time of sample and sample value for a number of days.  I would like to determine the time at which the minimum value for each day is measured:



Datetime
Value
Note




1/11/24 0:00
124.8
x


1/11/24 10:12
124.9



1/11/24 12:18
124.9



1/11/24 17:12
139.6



1/11/24 19:42
139.6



1/11/24 22:00
139.6



1/12/24 2:06
139.5



1/12/24 6:06
139.5



1/12/24 10:24
149.7



1/12/24 14:18
124.7



1/12/24 18:48
124.5
x


1/12/24 22:48
124.6



1/13/24 2:42
125



1/13/24 7:18
125.5



1/13/24 12:00
125.4



1/13/24 19:00
124.5
x


1/14/24 1:42
124



1/14/24 10:36
124



1/14/24 14:06
123.9
x


1/15/24 3:06
122.5
x


1/15/24 8:06
160.3



1/15/24 12:24
161




The "x's" mark the minimum values for ease of reference.
I can find the minimum value using either Query:
=ArrayFormula(query({int(A3:A),B3:B},"select Col1,min(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Date'"))




Date
Min




1/11/24
124.8


1/12/24
124.5


1/13/24
124.5


1/14/24
123.9


1/15/24
122.5



or Map/Lamda:
={"Date";arrayformula(unique(int(A3:A)))}

={"Min"; ArrayFormula( map( G3:G, lambda( date , if( date , round( minifs( B3:B, int(A3:A), int(date) ),2 ), ) ) ) )}

But cannot figure out how to extract the actual time at which the minimum values occur
A sample spreadsheet can be found at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nbHvJxv2alB9jwc4AJlweaXZvq-ukOHIlvBwnCGhjBc/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks


You may try:
=map(G3:G,lambda(Σ,+sort(ifna(filter(A:B,int(A:A)=Σ)),2,1)))



output column formatted to custom format h:mm

